# Why doesn't javascript take my JSON array?

Tags: php, javascript, alert

My php file ends with:

```
echo json_encode($array1);
echo ";";
echo json_encode($array2);
```

and prints out e.g.

> [1358499135965,68];[1358499140000,2]

My javascript code looks so:

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'livedata.php',
        success: function(point) {    
            var yenidata = point.split(";");
            alert(yenidata[0]);
            alert(yenidata[1]);
        });
    }
```

Why do I not get an alert?

Comment: Do you get any error on the console?

Comment: if your entire response is `[1358499135965,68];[1358499140000,2]`, then it is invalid JSON and may not be getting passed into the success handler.

Comment: oh yeah ... "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

Comment: You are missing a closing brace at the end.

Comment: You havent included jQuery library I guess

Comment: This php file and javascript is included in a bigger file. So jQuery library is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid.

Try:

```
echo '[';
echo json_encode($array1);
echo ",";
echo json_encode($array2);
echo ']';
```

Now the PHP page will print you: `[[1358499135965,68],[1358499140000,2]]`
Which can be parsed automatically as JSON using `dataType:"json"` in your ajax call.

When you include jQuery your code should look like:

```
function requestData() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'livedata.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(point) {
         console.log(point[0]); //Array [1358499135965,68]
         console.log(point[1]); //Array [1358499140000,2]
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: if he adds `dataType:"json"` to the ajax func, he doesn't even need to parse as json

Comment: But i have to echo ",;"; remove the ; ... echo ","; Now it works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` means you're not including [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You need to have that to use the features you're trying to use.

Comment: This php file and javascript is included in a bigger file. So jQuery library is included

Comment: Is it included *before* that JS?

Comment: Try `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$.ajax`